# Paypal mobile SDK - Single Payment transactions does not update in dashboard's transactions tab

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-mobile-sdk

In using paypal mobile sdk's, Here is how I understand how it will work as what I have read in the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/).

1. A drop-in will show that will prompt you to login.
2. Once logged in the payment will be processed and you will receive some kind of "proof-of-payment" data that will be forwarded to the server for verification.
3. The server will then fetch the payment data using the payment id
4. You as a developer should manually verify its "state" and the "transaction" object it contains.

After that, when I try to view if the said transaction is "done". I refresh the transactions tab in the sandbox dashboard and nothing appears. Is there a next procedure that I should do in order to confirm that these transactions really happened?

Also, is there an equivalent of the "[single payment](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#single-payment)" used in mobile sdks for websites As far as I know, there is no "web" sdk's provided that would produce a drop-in similar to the mobile sdk's.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a delay in the transactions appearing on sandbox. If you have a transaction id, you can do a [REST call to get its status](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource) to see if it has been approved.

The preferred solution for a drop-in option for web is [v.zero](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+python/guides/drop-in), once you integrate with it you have paypal as a payment option.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought first too but days already passed and there is no update in the transactions tab. I also already tried the REST call you linked using an express checkout transaction and it says invalid resource.

Comment: In that case, I doubt the transaction has been completed. If you are following the mobile sdk docs on https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#single-payment, it mentions how you can go about verifying the payment.